# Edited question still closed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

This is in regard to a [stata](/questions/tagged/stata) programming [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360137/how-to-export-dates-from-stata-to-excel) on Stack Overflow which has been closed by Bill the Lizard. The question has been edited, but it is still closed.

How can I re-open the question?

Comment: You can't. You need to collect reopen votes from the community who consider your question good enough to be reopened. Or a moderator has to judge it to be good enough. Looking at your question, I don't think it is. It is not even clear to me that you're actually asking a programming question. If you are, include your relevant code.

Comment: By the way, you apparently did nothing to improve your question. All edits were made by others and were merely a rephrasing and reformatting of the content already there. That is more than likely not going to be enough. You will actually have to make it a better, more clear question, relevant to the site.

Comment: @Mat d'oh, I overlooked that. But well, the comments are still valid I'd say.

Comment: @Metrics: I don't see how your edit helped clarify that question *at all*. I'm actually quite astounded that edit *even got approved*. Normally we'd want to *remove* things like "Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated." That's not useful to the question at all.

Comment: @Metrics If you are an experienced user, surely you can actually improve the question. (Actually improve it, and not like the edit you made before). The fact that it has a Stata tag does not automatically make it a clear and good programming question. And if you're saying only active users within a tag who are also moderators at the same time can close a question, I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was closed by a moderator as *not a real question* because the problem to be solved wasn't clearly stated.  In order to have a question reopened, five reopen votes from community members with at least 3000 reputation, or a reopen vote by a moderator, are needed.

To learn more about how closing and reopening works, see the privilege page on [voting to close and reopen.](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: Agree with CV as NARQ , [**Deleted by H2CO3, Servy, NullPointer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360137/how-to-export-dates-from-stata-to-excel)

Comment: @NullPointer: I am not a 10K user and so I cannot access the question.

Comment: here you go http://i.stack.imgur.com/43Ocv.png :)